# Preview: Highlights and Notes not showing in side panel

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

[Mac OS 10.13.2, Preview Version 10.0 (944.4)]

I have a large annotated PDF document and I would like to see a summary of these annotations on the `Highlights & Notes` side panel view, but nothing other than the side panel title is showing.  Is this a bug in my version of Preview?

I am able to get a list of annotations using `cmd-i` but this list does not show the details, like actual text, of annotations, nor does it allow me to jump to the annotation when I click on it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The side panel does not show annotations such as drawing and boxes. As the name implies, it will show text highlighted (underlined at least) and notes that are added using the notes option. One could attach a note when annotating a page and then clicking on the note from the sidebar will take the user to that page.

Showing thumbnail will show all the pages including all annotation on a page. Clicking on the thumbnail page takes you to that location.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I was expecting something similar to a search result to be shown when I select that side panel view.  I'm a bit surprised that the text annotations aren't showing in there.  With regards to line markings and highlights I would have thought there would at least be something there to indicate it's presence.  The thumbnail is useless for this as the pages are larger in the main view, thus easier to see, and can be scrolled through just as easily.